# autoincrement with prefix usr. sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i am not able to generete auto increment number with prefix usr. such as

usr001,

usr002 ...

need help

```
create procedure USP_PatientAdd
@patientID varchar(max),
@patientName varchar(max),
@patientAge varchar(max),
@patientSex varchar(max),
@patientFather varchar(max),
@patientAddr varchar(max),
@patientNumber varchar(max)
as
insert into PTN_DTL(
PTN_DTL_ID,  
   PTN_DTL_NAME,  
   PTN_DTL_AGE,  
   PTN_DTL_SEX,  
   PTN_DTL_FATHER,
   PTN_DTL_ADDR,
   PTN_DTL_NU
)
values (
'USR' + RIGHT('000000'+CAST((Select MAX() + 1 as varchar(6)),6),
@patientName,
@patientAge,
@patientSex,
@patientFather,
@patientAddr,
@patientNumber 
)
end
```

Comment: WHY? Just use an IDENTITY column and calculate `'USR0000x'` at query time. What purpose does storing `USR0000` in every single row of the table serve, other than to waste space?

Comment: sorry.. i am not able to get what you mean @Aaron Bertrand..

it is not an IDENTITY column. is't varchar(20)

Comment: And I'm saying ***use an IDENTITY column instead***. Why this is a varchar(20) I have no idea.

Comment: Ok.. i will.. but how shall i give a prefix to an identity coloumn values as USR00x

Comment: You shouldn't need to store the prefix if is is always the same. when you want to display the id column just concatenate the prefix with your identity column in your select statement.

Comment: Also you'd better set an alert for when the identity column gets close to 999999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to store this string anywhere, since the prefix will be the same on *every single row*. Just use an `IDENTITY` column, and calculate the `USR000...` prefix at query time, or in a view, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(id INT IDENTITY(1,1));
GO
INSERT dbo.foo DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 3
SELECT 'USR' + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), id), 6), id FROM dbo.foo;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.view_foo
AS
  SELECT foo_id = 'USR' + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), id), 6), id 
    FROM dbo.foo;
GO
SELECT foo_id, id FROM dbo.view_foo;
GO
```

If you really want this value stored (though I have no idea why you would need to, since the `USR000...` will be on every single row, and therefore have very little meaning and serve only to waste space), you could add a persisted computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD foo_id AS CONVERT(CHAR(9), 
  'USR' + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), id), 6)) PERSISTED;
```

Answer (score 1):

An identity column is going to be an integer.  So it will never be '000x', much less 'USR000x'.

If you really wanted to have USR stuck on the front of it, I guess you could have a column (that would have to be updated after the identity value is generated) that concatenates the values together. Or, as Aaron suggested, calculate it at run time, in a view, whatever. But that still won't give you the leading zeroes.